# Send a mail notification when clicking submit button

Tags: c#

I want to send a mail notification when a submit button is clicked. When I click the button, the Label is showing `your message has been sent`. But when I check my mail, I did not get that mail.

Here is my code:

```
  protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            //Create the msg object to be sent
            MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
            //Add your email address to the recipients
            msg.To.Add("sathishsatu222@gmail.com");
            //Configure the address we are sending the mail from **- NOT SURE IF I NEED THIS OR NOT?**
            MailAddress address = new MailAddress("satheezkumar93@gmail.com");
            msg.From = address;
            //Append their name in the beginning of the subject
            msg.Subject = "hy";
            msg.Body = "hy hw ru?";
            SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp-mail.gmail.com", 25);
            NetworkCredential credentials = new NetworkCredential("satheezkumar93@gmail.com", "mypassword here");
            client.Credentials = credentials;
            client.Host = "smtp-mail.gmail.com";
            client.Port = 25;
            client.EnableSsl = true;
            //Configure an SmtpClient to send the mail.


            //Display some feedback to the user to let them know it was sent
            lblResult.Text = "Your message was sent!";


        }
        catch
        {
            //If the message failed at some point, let the user know
            lblResult.Text = "Your message failed to send, please try again.";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why is this tagged `javascript`? That looks like Java. Is there even any HTML involved in this? `btnSubmit_Click` is the sort of thing I'd expect to see in a Swing or AWT UI (he said, showing how long along it has been since he did Java GUIs)

Comment: There's no code in there that actually sends the message - did you leave it out of the question, or is it not actually there in your code?

Comment: This is C#, not Java.

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually send the message:

```
client.Send(msg);
```

As a side note, it seems you are configuring your `SmtpClient` to be both on port 25 and use SSL, which is, while possible (not with gmail), not common.

Since you are using gmail, you should enable ssl (you are doing that already), and use port 587, not 25 (either do `client.Port = 587;`, or remove that line and change the `25` in the constructor for `587`).

Also, I believe the gmail host is `smtp.gmail.com`, not `smtp-mail.gmail.com`

Answer (score 0):

simplest mail method

```
protected void btnEmail_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
        vr txtmsg = "hello";
        var ToMail ="someone@some.com";

        using (MailMessage mm = new MailMessage(txtmsg , ToMail ))
        {
            mm.Subject ="Comments";
            mm.Body = "body text";

            mm.IsBodyHtml = false;
            SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
            smtp.Host = "yourhost";
            smtp.EnableSsl = true;
            //Provide those
            NetworkCredential NetworkCred = new NetworkCredential("username","pass");
            smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
            smtp.Credentials = NetworkCred;
            smtp.Port = 587;
            smtp.Send(mm);
            Response.Write("<script>alert('Mail Sent')</script>");
        }
    }
```

Gmail won't allow unauthorized login to send mail.

Kindly check OAuth to send mail.

Comment: when i am using mailrelay in the place of smtp-gmail.com..iam getting mail notification...

Comment: thats what i said.. you cannot access gmail smtp server directly. If you want to use gmail then you should consider oAuth2.0.